# Setting Permissions to different users in same Portlet Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

Is there a way I can set permissions to different users in a single portlet?

I want certain users to have access to certain jsp pages. Not all users should be allowed to use all pages in the same portlet.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: you can create Roles with specific permissions and assign that Role to specific users and check whether that user has role or not before displaying data

Comment: Lucky Boy:
Thanks! :)

Comment: let me know if you have any issue